# Swift hand over function as variable without running it at initialization

Tags: swift, function, struct, void

I want to define a Skill via the Skill-Struct which should have a flexible kind of function (in this example the skillActionsToArmor()).

```
struct Player {
    var armor:      Int
    var actions:    Int
    var skills:     [Skill]?
    
    init(actions: Int, armor: Int) {
        self.actions = actions
        self.armor   = armor
        self.skills  = [Skill(ID: 0, name: "Armor", function: skillActionsToArmor()  )]
    }
    
   mutating func skillActionsToArmor() {
        self.armor += self.actions
        self.actions = 0
    }
}


struct Skill {
   
    var ID       : Int
    var name     : String
    var function : ()
    
}
```

When I initiate the player, the function is directly executed, which is not the intention. I want to assign this Skill to a button later and it should be run on button press.

I was trying to define the function as:

```
var function: () -> Void
```

and then hand it over without ()

```
 self.skills  = [Skill(ID: 0, name: "Armor", function:
 skillActionsToArmor  )]
```

but then it gives me the following error:

> Escaping autoclosure captures 'inout' parameter 'self'

How can I modify the function variable or init to allow me to execute the function anytime later from the player struct?
E.g. with: `Player.skills[0].function()`

Comment: You can't make escaping references to methods belonging to a struct. Doing that would essentially turn them into class instances, which is what they're explicitly meant to not be. Either convert this to a `class`, or change it so this isn't a method: `func skillActionsToArmor(on player: Player)`. That way you can reference that `skillActionsToArmor` as a free-function, and call it by passing the player struct into it.

Comment: To explain the error,  a mutating function on a struct is essentially just a function that captures `self` (as `inout`, since it's mutating). You can't do that on a struct.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I was not able to get it working with a global function with (on: player), because I would still need to return the modified player back into the struct and override itself.
But I modified the skills to  "var skills: [Int]?" and just run a switch/case on the Int of the skill as a mutating func, not pretty but it works. :D Maybe I should try the class, but then I need to rewrite all modifying funcs and the way the player is handled from the game logic.

Comment: It appears to me that perhaps your player should be a `class`. That way you'll only have a single instance, with a stable identity, whose methods you can capture, pass around and call as you wish.